# in freemarker while reading the data from the controller it is not displaying the exact value it is doing rounging why?

Tags: java, sql, freemarker

this is my code:-fixed ,variable salary are store in data base like:14.40 and 300.70
while displaying these value in ui it display like fixed ,variable salary 14,301 it is doing round method. how to get exact value pzl any one.(employeeInfoForm)this is my obj contain all fields.

```
<tr>
    <th >Fixed salary:</th>
    <td>${(employeeInfoForm.fixedSalary)!'--'}</td> 

    <th >Variable Salary:</th>
    <td>${(employeeInfoForm.variableSalary)!'--'}</td>  
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things needed to keep in mind -

i) what are the types for `employeeForm.fixedSalary` and `employeeForm.variableSalary`? In other words, need to ensure that rounding does not happen before the value is fed in for replacement in template;

ii) check and see if number format is set in template, for e.g., `<#setting number_format="0.##">` rounds to two decimal places

Comment: yes i got the answer man :i have done like this <th>Fixed Salary:</th>
     <td>
      <input type="text" size="20" maxlength="100" name="fixedSalary" value="${(employeeInfoForm.fixedSalary?string.number)!}" />
     </td>                           or this one also is working out:-<th>Fixed Salary:</th>
     <td>
      <input type="text" size="20" maxlength="100" name="fixedSalary" value="${(employeeInfoForm.fixedSalary?c)!}" />
     </td> just i have use built in funtion of freemarker.any way thaks for yr answer man